# Binding not working with DI in Create/Edit action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement my controllers and views through interfaces. That should allow me to leave the concrete type binding to the DI container.

I tried just binding the properties to the interface. That gave me an exception telling me the default constructor could not be found:

> ArgumentException: Type 'Game.Models.IProduct' does not have a default
>   constructor

After some googling I found the [FromServices] attribute. Using that in my action signature instead of the bind attribute always returns an empty instance. Which makes sense because the properties were not bound to the form fields.

I thought to add both the attributes to the signature resulting in the code below. This still results in the same empty instance of Product. Note that the index and get edit actions work fine (constructor DI works).

I would prefer a solution using no other DI frameworks if possible.

Parameter name: type

addTest helper method:

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    internal static class ModelsInjector
    {
        public static void AddTest(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IDataProvider<IProduct>, ProductDataProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IProduct, Product>();
        }
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddTest();
        }
```

ProductController.cs

```
public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        protected readonly IDataProvider<IProduct> ProductProvider;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ProductController(IDataProvider<IProduct> dataProvider,
                                 ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            ProductProvider = dataProvider;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ProductController>();
        }


        // GET: Product/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(ProductProvider.Read(id));
        }

        // POST: Product/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,BaseValue,Name")][FromServices] IProduct product)
        {
            try
            {
                ProductProvider.Update(product);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```